# SQL query to divide value across rows that add to total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, rows, divide

Let's say I have the following

```
Col1         Col2
1            A      
1            A
1            A
1            B
1            B
1            B
1            B
2            A
2            A
2            B
3            A
3            A
3            A
3            A
3            A
3            A
```

What i need to do is write a query that determines the number of records for each combination of Col1 and Col2 and divide 1 by that number and assign that value to a new column (Col3), however I also need to update records in some cases so when summing the new column it always adds to one for each combination of Col1 and Col2.

So, in the first step I would end up with

```
Col1         Col2          NumberofRows
1            A             3
1            B             4
2            A             2
2            B             1
3            A             6
```

which when dividing by 1 produces

```
Col1         Col2         Col3
1            A            0.33
1            A            0.33
1            A            0.33
1            B            0.25
1            B            0.25
1            B            0.25
1            B            0.25
2            A            0.5
2            A            0.5
2            B            1
3            A            0.17
3            A            0.17
3            A            0.17
3            A            0.17
3            A            0.17
3            A            0.17
```

However when summing Col3 where Col1 = 1 and Col2 = A we end up with 0.99 instead of 1 for obvious reasons. Similarly, summing Col3 where Col1=3 and Col2=A we end up with 1.02.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can only store exact numbers if they can be expressed as a whole integer divided by a multiple of ten.  Since one third cannot be expressed that way, SQL Server cannot store one third without loss of precision.

A better option would be to store the row count.  Row counts are whole numbers and SQL Server can store them without loss of precision.  They will add up exactly to the total amount of rows.  And if you display the row, you can display `1/rc`.  What you display will never add up to one, but that is a limitation of displaying a number in decimal form.

If it's okay to display the number as a fraction, you could:

```
select  '1/' + cast(rc as varchar(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using CTE. 
  Please check my approach below :

```
;WITH c1 
AS
( SELECT col1, col2, count(*) as Cnt
  FROM test
  GROUP BY col1, col2
),
c2 
AS
( SELECT t.col1, t.col2, cast(cast(1 as decimal(5, 2))/grpCount.Cnt as decimal(5, 2))
  AS Cnt, 1%grpCount.Cnt AS roundedCount
  FROM test t
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM c1) AS grpCount
 ON grpCount.col1 = t.col1 AND grpCount.col2 = t.col2
)
SELECT * FROM c2;
```

SQL Fiddle :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe268/7

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that SQL uses the intermediate values as floats, but then cast to decimal 2 d.p when you display

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00fef/8)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO tableA 
VALUES
    (1,'A'),
    (1,'A'),
    (1,'A'),
    (1,'B'),
    (1,'B'),
    (1,'B'),
    (1,'B'),
    (2,'A'),
    (2,'A'),
    (2,'B'),
    (3,'A'),
    (3,'A'),
    (3,'A'),
    (3,'A'),
    (3,'A'),
    (3,'A')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH cnt
AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, 1.0 / COUNT(*)  cnt
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY Col1, Col2
)
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col2, CAST(SUM(cnt) AS decimal(4,2))
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN cnt
    ON A.Col1 = cnt.Col1 AND A.Col2 = cnt.Col2
GROUP BY A.Col1, A.Col2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00fef/8/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COLUMN_2 |
|------|------|----------|
|    1 |    A |        1 |
|    1 |    B |        1 |
|    2 |    A |        1 |
|    2 |    B |        1 |
|    3 |    A |        1 |
```